# Convert input text to list

Tags: javascript

I'm looking to convert a string of content into a list separated by ",".
The content should be inserted in a textbox by the user.

This is my html:

```
<textarea id="csv_text" onkeyup=""></textarea> 
                        <input onclick="convert_to_list()" value="Konvertera" type="button"/>
                    </fieldset>                 
                </form> 
                <div id="converted_list">
```

And this is the Javascript that I try to make work, but I can't get my head around it:

```
function convert_to_list() {
    var inputText= document.getElementById("csv_text").value;
    var inputText = input.split(",");
    document.getElementById("converted_list").innerHTML;
}
```

What am I doing wrong!?

Comment: document.getElementById("converted_list").innerHTML = inputText; ?????

Comment: If you want a comma separated list it doesn't make sense to `split(',')`. Provide sample of input and expected results as per [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate the created array and create a new div with the list item as content.

```
function convert_to_list() {
    var inputText= document.getElementById("csv_text").value;
    var splittedText = inputText.split(",");
    var anchor = document.getElementById("converted_list");
    splittedText.forEach(text => {
        var listItem = document.createElement("div")
        listItem.innerText = text
        anchor.appendChild(listItem)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java (since question is also marked with Java tag):

From text to list<sup>**1**</sup>:

```
List<String> convertToList(String text) {
      return Arrays.asList(text.split(",",-1));
}
```

From list to text:

```
String convertToText(List<String> list) {
    return String.join(",", list);
}
```

---

<sup>**1**: structure (size) of returned list cannot be changed - add `new ArrayList<>(...)` to create a fully modifiable list</sup>